# How to browse Metacello repositories in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, package-managers, metacello

I have downloaded Pharo 1.2.2 #12353 and wanted to install some packages in a easier way than going through Monticello Browser. I do not want to copy and paste scripts to install packages. After I opened the Menu, Tools, Configuration Browser a new window is shown with 3 ConfigurationOf...

ConfigurationOfFFI
ConfigurationOfMagma
ConfigurationOfVistaCursors

There is no help or description of what's the purpose of the Configuration Browser. What's one supposed to do with that?

- there is no way to select a repository of configurations
- there is no menu option to add a ConfigurationOf
- there is no way to browse the Configurations from that window

Besides, is that the right tool to browse a "Metacello Repository" like http://www.squeaksource.com/MetacelloRepository.html ?
There is a custom browser to Metacello? Why isn't included in the release by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [MetacelloBrowser](http://www.squeaksource.com/MetacelloBrowser.html) a try. It is aimed at providing a Metacello-centric interface for managing your project. The browser is still in development, but can be used for many tasks quite nicely.

If you decide to take it for a spin, please submit any issues [here](http://code.google.com/p/metacello/issues/entry). Join the [Metacello mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/metacello) if you have any questions or comments.

Dale

Answer (score 1):

Please report an issue about the *Configuration Browser* at http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/list and post your difficulties to the Pharo list. I played with the tool too and couldn't understand it either.

Comment: I posted it here: http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-project/2011-July/051860.html

Answer (score 1):

see

http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-project/2011-December/057409.html

and for its origins:

http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/detail?id=2752

The ideas is that we have an own Squeaksource repo (universe) for a
specific Pharo version where we have a copy all the ConfigurationOfXXX 
that are known to work in this specific Pharo version.

Since nobody (yet) mainted the one for Pharo 1.3 the browser is just empty.
I will try to find the time to fill the repo for Pharo 1.3